# Ejecutar una aplicación web en local

Tags: localhost

Tengo una curiosidad que seguro que me pueden resolver. Tengo una aplicación web, con su front y su back, funcionando en local mediante Xamp. Lo suyo es subirlo a un servidor y lanzarlo pero no voy a eso. Me surge la duda de si hay algún método para automatizar lo que ahora hago para ejecutar ese proyecto desde la consola, vamos que se "abra" Xamp automáticamente y se ejecute la aplicación.
Espero que se entienda lo que quiero.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Si xamp está instalado como servicio ya se ejecuta y si tu aplicación está en el directorio del servidor que se sirve, pues ya la tienes. No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Como dice @EvgeniEnchev, xamp debe de tener alguna opción para iniciar automáticamente cuando se inicia el sistema operativo. y para ejecutar la aplicacion podrías hacer una tarea programada donde abra /chrome con la direccion de localhost

Comment: Esto es un manual de como arrancar los servicios en XAMPP al iniciar windows. https://www.wikihow.com/Start-XAMPP-at-Startup-in-Windows . Una vez que apache este corriendo, si tu proyecto esta en _htdocs_, no deberías de necesitar nada más para correr el programa.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy probando